# Trying to sum values of inputs created by the user

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that generates the inputs all of class "priceInput" within a table.
And then a function that sums the values of that class.

I've tested the summing equation and I know it works if the "priceInput" class elements are in my html, but not when I have them created by the user. Please help!

```
 function newItem() {
    var tab;
    tab = document.createElement("div");
    tab.innerHTML = `
        <table><tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="descriptionLabel top priceContainer">Price: $</td>
                <td class="descriptionPrice"><input type="number" class="priceInput"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>`;
    document.getElementById("addtable").appendChild(tab);
  }

$(".priceInput").on("keyup", function () {
      let sum = 0;
      $(".priceInput").each(function () {
        sum += $(this).val() / 1;
      });
      $("#specialTotal").text(sum);
    });


<div class="buttonContainer">
      <button class="newItemButton" onclick="newItem()">Add New item</button>
</div>

<div id="addtable"></div>

<div class="total" id="specialTotal"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing this is happening because of a common problem. What I believe is happening is that when `$(".priceInput").on("keyup",...` is run, it attaches the event listener to the elements with `.priceInput` that exist **at the time of execution**  of this command.

As a result, any dynamically created elements with `.priceInput` do not have an event listener attached to them. There are two ways to fix this:

1. Attach the event listener each time to any new element you create.
2. Attach the listener to the whole document and verify if the `event.target` is the element that you wish it to be. If it is an element with `.priceTable` then do your summing.

**Fiddle applying method 1**: https://jsfiddle.net/a8b9whez/

**Fiddle applying method 2**: https://jsfiddle.net/t8e0obyk/3/

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example of the if statement I would use  if I was attaching the listener to the whole document?

Comment: @Haydn I'm trying to get that to work, for now I have linked a JS fiddle applying method 1 which is working as it should be

Comment: @Haydn This is what the if condition would look like: `if($(event.target).hasClass('priceInput'))` I have updated the answer regardless. If the answer helped you, you should select it as the correct answer to help others who might have the same problem :)

Comment: Just did! Thanks again, will be trying the second method as well